# Notepad++ direction bug(rtl/ltr)

Tags: notepad++, right-to-left, direction

When I try to change the direction of NotePad++ to rtl(right to left)
it looks like this:

[image]

(I wrote "Test").

please help me :)

Comment: It only happens the first time that you type. if you switch back and forth from another tab you'll see it gets fixed.

Comment: What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with a Notepad++ bug? Report it to the authors. This isn't the Notepad++ bug help desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug. To fix this problem, upgrade Notedpad++ to version v6.7+. (Confirmed working on v 6.7.5).

Answer (score 6):

To make it display correctly in RTL mode, just drag your window to change its size. It will be fixed automatically and look like this:

[image]

To switch it back to LTR, click `View -> Text Direction LTR`, or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be automatically. Can I do that?

Comment: @user3829526 I'm afraid that you cannot, AFAIK.